# Kibana server is not ready yet! Trying to visualize data push to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, connection, kibana, elk

I have this problem in the architecture:

```
kibana           | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-04-19T11:02:46+00:00","tags":["warning","elasticsearch"],"pid":7,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/"}
kibana           | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-04-19T11:02:46+00:00","tags":["warning","elasticsearch"],"pid":7,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana           | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-04-19T11:02:46+00:00","tags":["warning","plugins","licensing"],"pid":7,"message":"License information could not be obtained from Elasticsearch due to Error: No Living connections error"}
kibana           | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-04-19T11:03:16+00:00","tags":["warning","elasticsearch"],"pid":7,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/"}
kibana           | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-04-19T11:03:16+00:00","tags":["warning","elasticsearch"],"pid":7,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana           | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-04-19T11:03:16+00:00","tags":["warning","plugins","licensing"],"pid":7,"message":"License information could not be obtained from Elasticsearch due to Error: No Living connections error"}
```

I insert below the docker-compose from which I've not errors except for kibana, searching about the net I've seen the problem could be the memory requirment that I need to insert but if I insert deploy and then resource I've some problem issues related on docker

```
version: '2'
 services: 
  zookeeper:
   image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
   ports:
   - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
   build: .
   ports:
   - "9092:9092"
   expose:
   - "9093"
   environment:
     KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
     KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
     KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
     KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
     KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
     KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS:       "prova1:1:1,stream:1,1,output:1,1,input:1,1"
   volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  elasticsearch:
    restart: always
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.4.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
     - 9200:9200
    environment:
     - discovery.type=single-node
     - ES_JAVA_OPTS:"-Xms1g-Xmx1g"
  jobmanager:
   image: pyflink/playgrounds:1.10.0
   volumes:
    - ./examples:/opt/examples
   hostname: "jobmanager"
   expose:
    - "6123"
   ports:
    - "8088:8088"
   command: jobmanager
   environment:
    - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
  taskmanager:
   image: pyflink/playgrounds:1.10.0
   volumes:
    - ./examples:/opt/examples
   expose:
    - "6121"
    - "6122"
   depends_on:
    - jobmanager
   command: taskmanager
   links:
    - jobmanager:jobmanager
   environment:
    - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager 
  kibana:
   image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.12.0
   container_name: kibana
   restart: always
   ports:
    - 5601:5601
   environment:
     ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://localhost:9200
     ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: "http://localhost:9200"    
     elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve through the help of Elastic team. Here's a  [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/connectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-1-9200-and-server-is-not-ready/271776/10) that let to jump to community of elastic